# Mql4 Code Trailing Stop Loss not Moving on time

Tags: mql4

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                              CANDLE_HIGH_LOW.mq4 |
//|                                                      Hariprasath |
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Hariprasath"
#property link      ""
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double Lots = 0.01;
double minStopLossLevel = MarketInfo(_Symbol, MODE_STOPLEVEL) * Point;
double bidPrice = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_BID);
double askPrice = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_ASK);
double priceDifferece = askPrice-bidPrice;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   gettingPriceData();
   creatingLines();
   placeOrder();
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double gettingRecentHigh()
  {

   if(High[1] > High[2])
     {
      return High[1];
     }
   else
      return High[2];
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double gettingRecentLow()
  {

   if(Low[1] > Low[2])
     {
      return Low[2];
     }
   else
      return Low[1];
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void placeOrder()
  {
   double HighValue = gettingRecentHigh();
   double LowValue = gettingRecentLow();
   if(Ask > HighValue)
     {
      buyOrder();
      buyTrailingStopLoss();
     }

   if(Bid<LowValue)
     {
      sellOrder();
      selltrailingStopLoss();
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void gettingPriceData()
  {
   double recentHigh = gettingRecentHigh();
   double previousLow = gettingRecentLow();
   double AccountEquityBalance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY);
   double AccountProfitBalance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_PROFIT);

//Display price
   ObjectCreate("bidPrice",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("bidPrice",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("bidPrice",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("bidPrice",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,10);
   ObjectSetText("bidPrice","Bid Price : " + DoubleToStr(bidPrice,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("askPrice",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("askPrice",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("askPrice",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("askPrice",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,40);
   ObjectSetText("askPrice","Ask Price : " + DoubleToStr(askPrice,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("recentHigh",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("recentHigh",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_RIGHT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("recentHigh",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("recentHigh",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,10);
   ObjectSetText("recentHigh","Recent High : " + DoubleToStr(recentHigh,Digits),15,"Arial",White);


   ObjectCreate("previousLow",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("previousLow",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_RIGHT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("previousLow",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("previousLow",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,40);
   ObjectSetText("previousLow","Previous Low : " + DoubleToStr(previousLow,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("minStopLossLevel",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("minStopLossLevel",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_RIGHT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("minStopLossLevel",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("minStopLossLevel",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,70);
   ObjectSetText("minStopLossLevel","MinStopLossLevel : " + DoubleToStr(minStopLossLevel,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("priceDifferece",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("priceDifferece",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_RIGHT_UPPER);
   ObjectSet("priceDifferece",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,20);
   ObjectSet("priceDifferece",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,100);
   ObjectSetText("priceDifferece","PriceDifferece : " + DoubleToStr(priceDifferece,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("AccountEquityBalance",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("AccountEquityBalance",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_LOWER);
   ObjectSet("AccountEquityBalance",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,50);
   ObjectSet("AccountEquityBalance",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,10);
   ObjectSetText("AccountEquityBalance","Account Equity Balance : " + DoubleToStr(AccountEquityBalance,Digits),15,"Arial",White);

   ObjectCreate("AccountProfitBalance",OBJ_LABEL,0,0,0);
   ObjectSet("AccountProfitBalance",OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_LOWER);
   ObjectSet("AccountProfitBalance",OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,50);
   ObjectSet("AccountProfitBalance",OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,30);
   ObjectSetText("AccountProfitBalance","Account Profit Balance : " + DoubleToStr(AccountProfitBalance,Digits),15,"Arial",White);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void creatingLines()
  {

//Delete If existing lien
   ObjectDelete("RecentHighLine");

//Creating line
   ObjectCreate("RecentHighLine",OBJ_HLINE,0,Time[0], gettingRecentHigh());
   ObjectSet("RecentHighLine", OBJPROP_COLOR, clrGreen); // Line color
   ObjectSet("RecentHighLine", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2); // Line width
   ObjectSet("RecentHighLine", OBJPROP_RAY_LEFT, false); // Do not extend to the left
   ObjectSet("RecentHighLine", OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT, true); // Extend to the right

//Delete If existing lien
   ObjectDelete("PreviousLowLine");

//Creating line
   ObjectCreate("PreviousLowLine",OBJ_HLINE,0,Time[0], gettingRecentLow());
   ObjectSet("PreviousLowLine", OBJPROP_COLOR, clrRed); // Line color
   ObjectSet("PreviousLowLine", OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2); // Line width
   ObjectSet("PreviousLowLine", OBJPROP_RAY_LEFT, false); // Do not extend to the left
   ObjectSet("PreviousLowLine", OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT, true); // Extend to the right

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void buyOrder()
  {
   if(OrdersTotal() < 1)
     {
      // To place order
      int buyTicket =    OrderSend(
                            _Symbol,     //Currency Pair
                            OP_BUY,       // Order Type
                            Lots,       // Lot Size
                            Ask,         // Buying price
                            3,         // Slipage or tolorance
                            0,    //Stop loss
                            0,      //Profit
                            "BUY ORDER PLACED",    // Comments
                            0,            // Magic Number
                            0,                 // Expiation
                            Green             //Arrow allowed
                         );
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void buyTrailingStopLoss()
  {
   double HighValue = gettingRecentHigh();
   double LowValue = gettingRecentLow();

// To count total orders
   for(int a = OrdersTotal()-1; a>=0; a--)
     {
      //To select the orders
      if(OrderSelect(a,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
         //Check order with current order
         if(OrderSymbol() == Symbol())
            //To find the buy orders
            if(OrderType() == OP_BUY)
               //Fix the stop loss
               //   if(OrderStopLoss() < Ask)
               // Check and update the stop loss
               if(OrderStopLoss() != LowValue)
                  //We modify the stoploss
                  OrderModify(
                     OrderTicket(),    //For the current order
                     OrderOpenPrice(),   // Opended for the open price
                     LowValue,  //Set stop loss
                     OrderTakeProfit(), //Order Take profit
                     0,    //Expiration
                     Red
                  );
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void sellOrder()
  {
   if(OrdersTotal() < 1)
     {
      // To place order
      int sellTicket =    OrderSend(
                             _Symbol,     //Currency Pair
                             OP_SELL,       // Order Type
                             Lots,       // Lot Size
                             Bid,         // Buying price
                             3,         // Slipage or tolorance
                             0,    //Stop loss
                             0,      //Profit
                             "SELL ORDER PLACED",    // Comments
                             0,            // Magic Number
                             0,                 // Expiation
                             Red             //Arrow allowed
                          );
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void selltrailingStopLoss()
  {
     double HighValue = gettingRecentHigh();
   double LowValue = gettingRecentLow();
  // To count total orders
   for(int b = OrdersTotal()-1; b>=0; b--)
     {
      //To select the orders
      if(OrderSelect(b,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
         //Check order with current order
         if(OrderSymbol() == Symbol())
            //To find the buy orders
            if(OrderType() == OP_SELL)
               //Fix the stop loss
               //     if(OrderStopLoss() > Bid)
               //We modify the stoploss
               // Check and update the stop loss
               if(OrderStopLoss() != HighValue)
                  Alert("SELL WORKING");
      OrderModify(
         OrderTicket(),    //For the current order
         OrderOpenPrice(),   // Opended for the open price
         HighValue,  //Set stop loss
         OrderTakeProfit(), //Order Take profit
         0,    //Expiration
         Red
      );
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

Stoploss should be moved to green line but is not working properly working lately.

Like wise for buy order also expected SL is for red line but its coming below on that value

How to handle this kind of issues?

Comment: @James Z what you have edited pls specify

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trailing stop routine will never be executed since it is iterating backwards from `OrdersTotal()-1` :

```
 // To count total orders
   for(int b = OrdersTotal()-1; b>=0; b--)
```

and your `OrdersTotal()` will never be larger than 1:

```
void sellOrder()
{
if(OrdersTotal() < 1)
 {
  // To place order (...)
```

Besides that your code seems very redundant: the functions `gettingRecentHigh()` and `gettingRecentLow()` are both executed three times on each tick. Better store their results in a global variable and call the functions once per tick. Refer to the global var when needed elsewhere.